# Oracle "impdp" the 11g dump file to 12c - Unable to create user during import

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c, datapump, impdp

I have an Oracle datapump dump file exported from **Oracle 11gR2** which has been proven working fine when importing to another **Oracle 11gR2** environment. I want to import this dump file to my new environment which is running **Oracle 12c**.

I ran the "impdp" command to import this dump file as follows:

```
$> impdp system/password directory=KMS_DIR dumpfile='kms.dump' schemas=KMS_OWN 
   logfile=import.log
```

**The command worked perfectly with 11gR2 but it failed on 12c**

The error messages are shown as follows:

```
Starting "SYSTEM"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_01":  system/******** directory=KMS_DIR dumpfile=kms.dump schemas=KMS_OWN logfile=import.log 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER

**ORA-39083: Object type USER:"KMS_OWN" failed to create with error:**

ORA-65096: invalid common user or role name
Failing sql is:
 CREATE USER "KMS_OWN" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'S:19705E60DEEFDAF0C0F9E339228A66946376EA6453EB7186AF1C5C6D91E0;80B023397756355B' DEFAULT TABLESPACE "KMS_LH_DATA_TBS" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
ORA-39083: Object type SYSTEM_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01917: user or role 'KMS_OWN' does not exist
```

*It has nothing to do with the tablespace and directory, I have them well prepared so the command worked with 11g perfectly.*

Also, due to the fact that Oracle data pump has failed to create the user, it then failed all consequent import operations. I have searched through lots of articles and ***Oracle 12c likely doesn't allow creating the common user with C## prefix***. However, I'm not 100% sure if this is the issue but it seems like this is a big difference with 11g.

How can I cope with this? Is it really possible to import the dump file from Oracle 11gR2 to the 12c environment with "impdp"?

Comment: Are you connecting to (i.e. running impdp against) the container database or a pluggable database?

Comment: Also see [the documentation about impdp and CDBs/PDBs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-49A847B1-3193-4C45-B7F3-B7F514B75C71.htm).

Comment: I connected to CBS$ROOT, I guess this is the default container.

Comment: The `IDENTIFIED BY VALUES` looks weird to me. Are both databases configured the same from the security point of view (e.g. case sensitive password?)